# Dates are returning as seconds

Tags: r, date

I have a character vector of dates that I would like convert into a different timezone.

```
 pubdate
[1] "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 03:21:23 +0000" "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 03:04:55 +0000"
[3] "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:49:01 +0000" "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:30:37 +0000"
 [5] "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:27:44 +0000" "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:16:46 +0000"
 [7] "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:14:06 +0000" "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:10:20 +0000"
 [9] "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:07:52 +0000" "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 22:37:41 +0000"
[11] "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 22:35:06 +0000"
```

I created a function to this.

```
temp <- as.matrix(0)

    for (i in 1:length(pubdate)){
            tmp_dta <- strptime(pubdate[[i]],format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
            tmp_dta$hour <- tmp_dta$hour - 1
            tmp_dta <- as.POSIXct(tmp_dta)
            attributes(tmp_dta)$tzone <- "Asia/Manila" 
            temp[i] <- tmp_dta

    }
```

however, when i tried to print temp data, it seems to return the number of seconds. Here

```
> temp
 [1] 1436494883 1436493895 1436482141 1436481037 1436480864 1436480206 1436480046 1436479820
 [9] 1436479672 1436477861 1436477706
```

May I know how I can change it to return as dates? example: "2015-07-10 10:21:23 PHT"

Thanks!

UPDATED: As suggested by Nicola below, I removed the looping and added his suggested code. Below code works:

```
tmp_dta <- strptime(pubdate,format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

    x <- as.POSIXct(tmp_dta)

    attributes(x)$tzone <- "Asia/Manila" 

    newpubdate <- x - 3600
```

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(1436494883, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Asia/Manila" )`

Comment: No need of looping. Just try `as.POSIXct(pubdate,format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", tz="Asia/Manila")`

Comment: @nicola; the reason why I need to loop is because of this line tmp_dta$hour <- tmp_dta$hour - 1. When I convert it to Asia Manila time, the resulting time is an hour ahead of the expected time. im expecting to have "2015-07-10 10:21:23 PHT", but results would be "2015-07-10 11:21:23 PHT" if I dont subtract 1 hour.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The time should be converted correctly. However, to subtract one hour, you can just subtract 3600. If `x` is the object resulting from my line, `x-3600` does the trick, as well as `x-as.difftime(1,units="hours")`.

Comment: i tried to use the code 'as.POSIXct(pubdate,format="%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", tz="Asia/Manila")' but it only change the timezone, not convert the whole date to PHT time. Sample result: "2015-07-10 03:21:23 PHT". Expected output should be "2015-07-10 11:21:23 PHT"

Comment: I made some edits, and I was able to make it work. I edited my post to include the solution. Thanks for your help Nicola!

Comment: I spoke to soon, when i print out the resulting table, its not the date that is printed but the numbers (eg. 1436494883). may i know why its behaving this way?

Comment: When I use the line I suggested in my comment, the first value I obtain is `2015-07-10 11:21:23 PHT`. Your example in the question works also for me.

Comment: i think this is behaving differently. I was able to solve the problem b converting the variable to character i.e as.character(newpubdate) solves it. Thanks for the help nicola!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole operation in one single line:

```
pubdate <- c( "Fri, 10 Jul 2015 03:21:23 +0000" ,"Fri, 10 Jul 2015 03:04:55 +0000","Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:49:01 +0000", "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:30:37 +0000","Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:27:44 +0000", "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:16:46 +0000","Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:14:06 +0000","Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:10:20 +0000", "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 23:07:52 +0000", "Thu, 09 Jul 2015 22:37:41 +0000","Thu, 09 Jul 2015 22:35:06 +0000")
strptime(pubdate,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",tz="Asia/Manila")
# [1] "2015-07-10 11:21:23 PHT" "2015-07-10 11:04:55 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:49:01 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:30:37 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:27:44 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:16:46 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:14:06 PHT" "2015-07-10 07:10:20 PHT"
# [9] "2015-07-10 07:07:52 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:37:41 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:35:06 PHT"
```

If you think there is a one-hour discrepancy (which I don't think there is: have you thought of daylight-saving time?), then, as @nicola suggested:

```
strptime(pubdate,"%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z",tz="Asia/Manila") - as.difftime(1,unit="hours")
# [1] "2015-07-10 10:21:23 PHT" "2015-07-10 10:04:55 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:49:01 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:30:37 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:27:44 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:16:46 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:14:06 PHT" "2015-07-10 06:10:20 PHT"
# [9] "2015-07-10 06:07:52 PHT" "2015-07-10 05:37:41 PHT" "2015-07-10 05:35:06 PHT"
```